# How do I fix this error of library(copula) with R?

Tags: r, warnings, r-package

```
library(copula)
```

I think I have installed the package `copula` with R. I can see it in installed packages. But when I try to use it, it gives the error below. I don't understand this. What should I do to make it right?

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘copula’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'D:/R-4.0.0/library/gsl/libs/x64/gsl.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘copula’ was built under R version 4.0.3
```

Comment: Sound like the install didn't quite work. Did you use `install.packages("copula")` to install it? Maybe restart R and try reinstalling the package again.

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, I did. And thank you, I'll try.